# Sort List of class by string of ID's

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, sorting

I've got a string of comma separated ID's.

(through a SQL SP) I'm retrieving values to populate a List Of Class "ProductInfo" which has a property for ID and a property for Name.

After the List has been populated, I want to sort the list by the ID's according to the original Strings order.

The SP being used to retrieve the data is ordering by ID ASC, and I am not able to change the SP.

```
Public Class ProductInfo
    Private _id as String
    Public Property ID as String
        ..get..
        ..set..
    End Property

    Private _name as String
    Public Property Name as String
        ..get..
        ..set..
    End Property
End Class


Dim strIds as String = "56312,73446,129873,49879,38979"

Dim Products As New List(Of ProductInfo)
Products = FillProductDetails(strIds)

Products.Sort(strIds) ''''Conceptual
```

Comment: I think if ProductInfo overrides `.ToString` to return the ID, then `Products.Sort()` is all you need.  otherwise, you probably need to provide a comparer which provides the sort smarts: `Sort(comparer As System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of T))`

Comment: you could also use a `SortedList` instead maybe.  the problem of course is that a text comparer will fail with something like `{"9011", "100003"}` "9011" will sort higher than "1000003" which is something an IComparer can handle/convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it in a God Tier language.

```
var sortedList = strIds.Select(x => Products.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == x));
```

I am not familiar with your savage script, but you may be able to translate.

*Note*, it is better to use an array of IDs rather than a comma separated list.

```
var strIds = new[] {"56312", "73446", "129873", "49879", "38979", };
```

Makes it easier to use in code.

Mark was kind enough to provide the translation to moonspeak:

```
Dim sortedList = strIds.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.ID = x))
```

Or, with strIds as an array

```
Dim sortedList = strIds.Select(Function(x) Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.ID = x))
```

Comment: You need to split `strIds` so you don't look for each character, but here is the "savage" version: `Dim sortedList = strIds.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) Products.FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.ID = x))`

Comment: @Mark: Aaah, yeah, it wasn't an array.  I'll clarify that.  And thanks for the translation into moonspeak.

Comment: This works! Don't know how, but I will analyze this alien code to learn it's ways.   +5 for God Tier -> Moonspeak  (@Mark ©)

Comment: @adam: What the Select method does is essentially "For each item in this enumerable, perform a user-defined transform and return the result".  The enumerable is the list of IDs, each of which is passed to the user-defined function, in order.  In the function, I'm looking into Products for the first product that has that ID, and returning it.  So, it passes in 56312, and I find the product with the ID 56312.  Then it passes in 73446, and etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Going along with your conceptual usage of `Products.Sort`, here's an attempt at using the overload that takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate.

First split the ids string into an array.

```
Dim straIds As String() = strIds.Split(","c)
```

Then order by position within the array. An inline version:

```
Products.Sort(Function(x, y) If(Array.IndexOf(straIds, x.Id) > Array.IndexOf(straIds, y.Id), -1, If(Array.IndexOf(straIds, x.Id) = Array.IndexOf(straIds, y.Id), 0, 1)))
```

Or a more readable version:

```
    Products.Sort(Function(x, y) 
                      Dim i As Integer = Array.IndexOf(straIds, x.Id)
                      Dim j As Integer = Array.IndexOf(straIds, y.Id)
                      Return If(i > j, -1, If(i = j, 0, 1))
                  End Function)
```

Not sure if it will work as written, but there's an attempt to provide a `Comparison` delegate that preserves the order in your original `strIds` string.